# Reusing tableViewCell with UITextFields gives same data from an Array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a section with custom tableViewCell and this cell has two text fields. 
This cell is used to display phone number of a user - country code in one text field and the number in other text field.

I fetch data from a service and if the user has more than one phone, based on the count of the phones, I am updating numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath. I do not have any issue till here.

For example, if user has two phones, I return 2 in numberOfRowsInSection, and shows two cells (same custom cell with two textFields).

**The Problem:**
I get the same data - the second phone number details - in both the cells. But I need to have list of phone numbers displayed one after the other in my custom cell textfields.

**Here is my code**:

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
    public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            switch section {

            case 3:                
                return (user.phones?.count)!

            default:
                return 1

            }
    }
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
     case .ContactPhones:
            if contactCellExpanded == true {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PhoneCell") as? PhoneCell

            }
        case .ContactEmail:
            if contactCellExpanded == true {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EmailCell") as? EmailCell
            }

        default:
            break


}
```

**PhoneCell**

```
import UIKit

class PhoneCell: ProfileCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var countryCode: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var addPhoneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var teleNumber: UITextField!


    @IBAction func addPhoneButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    override func configure(withUser user: XtraUser, language: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        super.configure(withUser: user, language: language, indexPath: indexPath)

        self.countryCode.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
        self.teleNumber.borderStyle = .RoundedRect

        if let userPhoneInfo = user.phones {
            for i in 0..<userPhoneInfo.count {
                print ("numbers \(userPhoneInfo[i].number)")
                self.countryCode.text = userPhoneInfo[i].country
                self.teleNumber.text = userPhoneInfo[i].number
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that I am using a for loop to get the numbers list when available, but how do I assign each value to the cell's textField?

Please Help!
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in configure method you know the index path of the cell why dont you just use

```
override func configure(withUser user: XtraUser, language: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    super.configure(withUser: user, language: language, indexPath: indexPath)

    self.countryCode.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    self.teleNumber.borderStyle = .RoundedRect

    print("Enumerated \(user.phones?.enumerate())")

    if let userPhoneInfo = user.phones {
        self.countryCode.text = userPhoneInfo[indexPath.row].country
        self.teleNumber.text = userPhoneInfo[indexPath.row].number
    }
}
```

But anyway the best solution is  to have model for each cell and pass it to this configure method.

Comment: I have an extending question to my original question. Could you help me please?
User can also add Phones - I have an Add button and increasing the count of "user.phones?.count". But whenever I click on Add, it clears the values in textFields. Not able to figure out why!

Comment: Well put breakpoint in configure method and check what happens after you click Add button. Maybe on some point you populate textfields with empty strings ? It must be debugged.

Comment: Yes, i already did debugging there. I see there is an empty string. I posted a new question on SO here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394099/swift-uitextfield-text-clears-with-button-action-in-tableviewcell?noredirect=1#comment69991724_41394099

Answer (score 0):

Wrong logic implementation in numberOfRows method.
In that method set number of rows according to your data in response.

Comment: It indeed returns the number of rows from the data in response. I am not sure if you are indicating anything else. I get the number of Rows as in my response. But difficulty is with updating data in textfields of my cell.

Comment: look,you have set switch case according to section.but you have only one section as i think , so there should not be switch case there.

Comment: I am showing only the cases that are relevant to my PhoneCell. But there are 4 other cases, did not post in my question to avoid lot of code lines