# Swift UITextField text clears with button action in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have recorded my screen and [here is the link to it](http://recordit.co/j4OKygOkaJ).
Going into details

1. I have a tableView section, in which there is a tableviewcell (**PhoneCell**) with two textfields (one is a pickerview input and other a textfield), and an Add Button.
2. When Add button is tapped, I am appending an empty phone to the array of phones (reusing the same PhoneCell) and calling `tableView.reloadData()` method.

**The Problem :(**
Whenever I tap on Add button, the textFields text that I enter is cleared. I would like to retain it and ultimately should be able to save data (number of phones the user entered) when I click **Save_Button**

**Add Phone Button action code:**

```
func addUserPhone(userData: MyUserData) {
        self.user = userData

        var emptyPhoneDict:[String:String] = ["country":"", "number":""]

        if (user.phones?.count < 4) {
            var emptyPhone : MyUserPhoneNumber = MyUserPhoneNumber(dictionary: emptyPhoneDict)!
            emptyPhone.country = ""
            emptyPhone.number = ""
            user.phones?.append(emptyPhone)
        }
    }
```

In my **PhoneCell.swift** class, I have the below method that is taking care of data and indexPath values

```
override func configure(withUser user: MyUserData, language: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        super.configure(withUser: user, language: language, indexPath: indexPath)

        configureCountryCodePicker()
        fetchCountryTeleCodeList()

        userInfo = user

        self.countryCode.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
        self.teleNumber.borderStyle = .RoundedRect

        if user.phones?.count == 0 {
            self.countryCode.text = ""
            self.teleNumber.text = ""
        }

        else {
            if let userPhoneInfo = user.phones {

                self.countryCode.text = userPhoneInfo[indexPath.row].country
                self.teleNumber.text = userPhoneInfo[indexPath.row].number

            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT (ADDED cellForRowAtIndexPath)**

```
public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let section = Section(rawValue: indexPath.section) else {
            print("❌ Invalid section index.")
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        let expanded = expandedCellPaths.contains(indexPath)

        var cell: ProfileCell?

        switch section {       

        case .ContactPhones:
            if contactCellExpanded == true {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PhoneCell") as? PhoneCell
                (cell as? PhoneCell)?.dataSource = self

                if user.phones?.count == 4 {
                    (cell as! PhoneCell).addPhoneButton.hidden = true
                }
                else {
                    (cell as! PhoneCell).addPhoneButton.hidden = false
                }

            }
        case .ContactEmail:
            if contactCellExpanded == true {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EmailCell") as? EmailCell
            }

        default:
            break
        }

        cell?.configure(withUser: user, language: languageCode, indexPath: indexPath)
        cell?.delegate = self

        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()

    }
```

**EDIT 2 (added addPhoneButtonAction)**

```
@IBAction func addPhoneButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dataSource?.addUserPhone(userInfo!)
    }
```

Where `dataSource` is variable of type PhoneCellDataSource protocol

```
protocol PhoneCellDataSource : class {

    func fetchCountryTeleCodeList(completion:((XtraResult<NSArray, XtraError>) -> Void))
    func addUserPhone(userData: MyUserData)

}
```

I can share more inputs/code as required. Please help. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Nicely created GIF for solution lohit... :) Could you please chare your cellForRowAtIndexPath code?

Comment: @DheerajD: thank you :-)
I added cellForRowAtIndexPath in my question

Comment: @LohithKorupolu Can you show the button action of `addPhoneButton`?

Comment: addPhoneButton will be also required to know the issue.

Comment: done! added addPhoneButtonAction

Comment: When you're reloading tableView index or section or complete tableview after addition of `userData`?

Comment: @MuhammadRaza, I am reloading complete tableView

Comment: Can you please try reload after addition? I think reloading is occuring before addition

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question ;-)

TextFeilds are only boxes that accommodate some data (text). And since I was reusing the Phonecell each time I add a new row, the text I entered gets erased. This is because it is not "**stored/saved**" in the user object.

So in my addPhoneButtonAction method, I added this -

```
@IBAction func addPhoneButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        userInfo?.phones![myIndexPath!.row].country = countryCode.text!
        userInfo?.phones![myIndexPath!.row].number = teleNumber.text!

        self.dataSource?.addUserPhone(userInfo!)
    }
```

Where myIndexPath is the indexPath of the row :-)

The working [sample is here](http://recordit.co/0oCl4iCICU)